# StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction in JPA

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have the ManyToOne Relationship in "Letter.java" as follows;

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Letter inResponseTo;
```

With one Letter object multiple inResponseTo of the same Letter type of objects are associated.For the Letter object all the inResponseTo objects are getting updated so initially i am merging() them within the loop and finally persisting() the Letter object as follows;

```
private void saveCorrespondence(List<Letter> letterList,
            final Claimant claimant) {
        for (Letter letter : letterList) {
            if(letter.getLetterCode() == null) {                
                if(letter.getMailType() == MailType.OUTGOING) {
                    letter.setLetterCode(LetterCode.findByCode("701"));
                } else if(letter.getMailType() == MailType.INCOMING) {
                    letter.setLetterCode(LetterCode.findByCode("109"));
                }
            }   
            letter.setClaimant(claimant);
            if (letter.getId() != null) {
                letter = letter.merge();
                letter.flush();
            }
            letter.persist();//Here in this line i am getting an error.
        }
    }
```

Note:-Claimant and Letter have OneToMany relationship.
While persisting getting the Error as StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction JPA in the same Line.How I can fix this please help me.